# Need advise : how to handle huge data to summarise a report in php

Tags: zend-framework2, query-optimization

I am looking for advice to handle following situation.

I have report which shows list of products; each product has a number of times it has been viewed and also the number of times the order has been requested.

Looking in to DB I feel its not good. There are three tables participating :

- `product`
- `product_view`
- `order_item`

The following SELECT query is executed

```
select product_title, 
(select count(views) from product_view  pv where p.pid=pv.pid) as product_view , 
(select count(placed) from order_item o where p.pid=o.pid) as product_request_count
From product p
order by product_title
Limit 0,10
```

This query returns 10 records successfully; However, it is very time consuming to load. Also when the user uses the export functionality approximately 2,000,000 records would be returned however I get a memory exhaust error.

I am not able to find the most suitable solution for this in ZF2[PHP+MySql]

Can someone suggest some good strategy to deal?

Answer (score 0):

How about using background processes? It doesn't have to be purely ZF2.

And once the background process is done, the system will notify to user via email that the export is done. :)

Comment: I thought of this but with background, report will not reflect the latest updates...and with some reason downloading 50 MB via http[force download option] is also giving me challenge...

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- call `set_time_limit(0)` to inter the execution time limitation.
- loop through the whole result set in lumps of, say, 1000 records, and output to the user the result sequentially.

Comment: just to understand you mean define chunk and download them in multiple excel sheet?

Comment: No. You proccess your data in chunks, but the output is single.